# which numerical method for solving $f(x) = 0$ if the solution is unique?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

> Which numerical method for solving $f(x) = 0$ if the solution of the nonlinear equation is unique? We only assume that function $f$ is continuous.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you require unique solutions?

Comment: $f$ could be arbitrary close to $0$ (not being $0$) infinitely many times which could give infinitely many false positives.

Comment: Yes, assume that the solution of $f = 0$ is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need a bit more than just uniqueness of the solution of $f(x) = 0$ for this to be guaranteed to work: if $f$ takes both positive and negative values, you can search for $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ have opposite signs, then 
use [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

On the other hand, if all you know is that $f$ is continuous and the solution to $f(x) = 0$ is unique, then it's hopeless: there is no way for your numerical method to detect whether the solution is in a given interval.